# Is there a handy integrable test function with a polynomial decay and a compactly supported Fourier transform?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

From what I am aware of, let the function $\varphi$ be
$$\varphi(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\pi^2-4x^2}.$$
One can easily show that $\varphi\in L^1$ and its tail has a polynomial decay $\varphi\sim x^{-2}$. Its Fourier transform is
$$\hat\varphi(s)=c\cos(\pi s/2),\quad s\in(-1,1)$$
with a proper constant $c$ depending on the convention of Fourier transform. Also it is easily seen that $\hat\varphi$ has a compact support.

My question is, is there a generalisation of this test function such that $\varphi_k\in L^1$, $\hat\varphi_k$ has a compact support, and $\varphi_k$ decays like $x^{-k}$ for a fixed $k$? The previous one is like $\varphi_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For even values of $k$ you may just consider

$$\varphi_{2m}(x) =\frac{\cos(x)}{\prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)}=\prod_{n > m}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)$$
given by the Weierstrass product for the cosine function. For odd values of $k>1$ you can do essentially the same with the Weierstrass product for the sine function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work. Could you elaborate a bit more on how this idea is come up with?

Comment: With a bit of luck, I guess: yesterday I solved an integral, $\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left|\cos(\pi e^{i\theta})\right|\,d\theta$, by exploiting the Weierstrass product for the cosine function, and I immediately wondered if the same could be applied here. It could, indeed.